# Geometrical Interpretation of $y = x - \frac{u \cdot T(x)}{T(u)}$ for all $x\in X.$

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, normed-spaces

I asked the following question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2310328/if-tx-0-implies-that-sx-0-show-that-there-is-a-constant-c-such-th).

> Let $X$ be a normed vector space and suppose $T$ and $S$ are in $X^*.$
>       If $T(x) = 0$ implies that $S(x) = 0,$ show that there is a constant $c$ such that $S(x) = c \cdot T(x)$ for all $x \in X.$

Kelenner suggested the following:

> Suppose that there exists $u\in X$ such that $T(u) \neq 0.$ For all $\in X,$ put $y = x-\frac{u\cdot T(x)}{T(u)}.$

**Question:** What is the geometrical interpretation of $y = x - \frac{u \cdot T(x)}{T(u)}?$

I am thinking maybe it is related to similar triangles concept, that is, if $X=\mathbb{R},$ pick $x \not\in \ker{T},$ assume that $\|u\|>\|x\|.$ 
Also assume that the images $T(x)$ and $T(u)$ are positive. By linearity of $T,$ the points $0,x, T(x), u$ and $T(u)$ form two similar triangles. However, I have no idea on how to relate this to the equation $y=x-\frac{u\cdot T(x)}{T(u)}.$

Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know for sure. The one remark I want to make is the following. Assume that we actually had a Hilbert space, and the very special case that $T(x)=\langle x,u\rangle$. In that case the mapping
$$P:x\mapsto x-\frac{T(x)u}{T(u)}$$ would be the orthogonal projection to the subspace $\perp$ to $u$. In other words $P\circ P=P$ (=> projection), and $P(x)\perp u$ for all $x$. In your case a few of those features survive. You still have $P\circ P=P$, and you also have $T(P(x))=0$ for all $x$. This was all pretty elementary. Sorry if I wasted your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $T \neq 0$, then $\ker T$ is of codimension one in $X$. By choosing $u \in X$ such that $Tu \neq 0$, you are choosing a one-dimensional complement for $\ker T$ and then $X = \ker T \oplus \operatorname{span} \{ u \}$. The map $x \mapsto x - \frac{Tx}{Tu} u$ is just the projection onto the factor $\ker T$ in the direct sum decomposition. By the way, you don't need to assume that $X$ has a norm, this works for arbitrary vector spaces.

To see the geometry more clearly, you can consider the case where $X = \mathbb{R}^n$. If $T \neq 0$, then $\ker T$ is a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and by choosing $u$ such that $Tu \neq 0$, you choose a vector that doesn't lie in this hyperplane. For $\mathbb{R}^n$, you can choose for example $u$ which is orthogonal to $\ker T$. Then you can decompose any vector in $X$ as a sum of two vectors - one which lies in the hyperplane $\ker T$ and one which is a scalar multiple of $u$. Your map gives you the projection onto the hyperplane.